# Do any ATC displays use colours to indicate altitude?

Tags: air-traffic-control, radar, display

I've been [thinking](http://www.yankee-dreamer.com/3dradar.htm) about how ATC displays present information to operators and it seems that colour isn't used, at least for critical information like altitude. Since our eyes can recognize colour more quickly than they can read numbers, using colour to display altitudes seems like it would be helpful for operators.

Do any existing ATC displays use colour to encode altitude?

Comment: I can't see any use for this.  At the 9 o'clock position, there are two yellow (medium altitude) aircraft heading towards each other.  Are they at the same altitude?  What do "high", "medium" and "low" mean? [Here](http://www.oocities.org/rjt02/images/aircraft_tag.jpg), I can see instantly.

Comment: I feel that [more questions](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/11211/richard-magoon) linking to your site would be more a way to promote it than to get answers to satisfy your curiosity.

Comment: Thinly conceiled spam.

Comment: @Simon that image should say "altitude in hundreds of feet", I've never seen a data block display thousands. Or that aircraft is at FL600. Which is cool, in it's own way. :)

Comment: @falstro 060 is 6,000 feet.  It's effectively a flight level.

Comment: @falstro Doh, yes, I just remembered :), but it looks right, 060 is 6,000 feet.

Comment: @Simon exactly, it's in hundreds, 60 * 100 = 6 000 ft. It states that it's in thousands of feet, which would be 60 * 1000 = 60 000 ft.

Answer (score 7):

That isn't a "three-dimensional radar display". It is a two-dimensional display with altitude encoded as color.

Current ATC radar is two-dimensional, with altitude encoded as a number:
[image: ATC Target example]

A true Three-Dimensional Radar would look something like this:
[image: 3D Radar Tank]
(Photo liberally thieved from a *1956* edition of [Popular Electronics](http://www.rfcafe.com/references/popular-electronics/electronic-inventions-needed-january-1956-popular-electronics.htm).)

---

As far as 2D radar goes, I don't believe color-coding the targets as described in the linked implementation would provide an improvement over the existing system: It's based on "bands of interest", which means you need to *define what you're interested in*, which means keystrokes - the controller is typing in what altitude they're working with to change the colors so they can see any conflicts, then they will need to change to the next altitude of interest, etc. - a lot of work versus "This number is within 10 of that number. There may be a conflict if these aircraft get too close to each other."

In addition color-coding the targets as described forecloses other possible uses of color in the system, and doesn't eliminate the need to display the altitude (controllers still need to know the precise altitude of an aircraft to determine how far off its assigned altitude it is -- in fact *that* may be a more apt use of color coding).

Comment: I guess in 1956 Popular Electronics didn't think much of Texas, huh?

Comment: @mins We're all living in the holodeck on the Enterprise!

Comment: `liberally thieved` - well played!

Comment: @mins We've been trying to give it back to Mexico for years, but they still remember the Alamo.